# prerequisite .net framework 3.5 sp1 in setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation

I Included framework 3.5 sp1 in my setup and chose the option: "download prerequisites from the same location as my application",
but it doesn't do that.Instead, when installed I see a message that tells me to go download framework 3.5 sp1 from web.
what am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should do the trick.
Make sure the Name of the .NET setup file is the one Visual Studio is expecting. Also, check out: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Prerequisites_in_Setup.aspx to make sure everything is in place.